# Selenium Webdriver click specific WebElement

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have the following html and would like the `td` with `class` `tree-label-name ng-binding` and `text()` `Approver` to be selected (clicked)

HTML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<treecontrol tree-model="vm.homeStats" expand-level="0" on-selection="vm.selectStatsNode(node)" on-node-toggle="vm.toggleTreeNode(node, expanded)" expanded-nodes="vm.expandedNodes" selected-node="vm.selectedNode" class="ng-isolate-scope">
   <ul class="ng-scope">
      <li ng-repeat="node in node.children | filter:filterExpression:filterComparator" ng-class="headClass(node)" class="ng-scope tree-collapsed tree-selected">
         <i class="tree-branch-head" ng-class="iBranchClass()" ng-click="selectNodeHead(node)"></i><i class="tree-leaf-head "></i>
         <div class="tree-label  tree-selected" ng-class="selectedClass()" ng-click="selectNodeLabel(node)" tree-transclude="">
            <table class="ng-scope">
               <tbody>
                  <tr>
                     <td class="tree-label-icon"><img bf-image-path="user" class="tree-icon" src="/Assets/img/icons/user.png"></td>
                     <td class="tree-label-name ng-binding">
                        Strydom, AJ (Rico)<br>
                        <progress-bar ng-if="::!node.isFolder" value="6" max-value="230" class="ng-scope">
                           <div class="progress-bar" ng-style="barStyles">
                              <div class="progress-bar-value" ng-style="valueStyles" style="width: 2.6087%;"></div>
                           </div>
                        </progress-bar>
                     </td>
                     <td width="30" class="text-right">
                      <strong class="process-bar-total ng-binding ng-scope" ng-if="::!node.isFolder">6</strong><!-- end ngIf: ::!node.isFolder -->
                     </td>
                  </tr>
               </tbody>
            </table>
         </div>
      </li>
      <li ng-repeat="node in node.children | filter:filterExpression:filterComparator" ng-class="headClass(node)" class="ng-scope tree-collapsed">
         <i class="tree-branch-head" ng-class="iBranchClass()" ng-click="selectNodeHead(node)"></i><i class="tree-leaf-head "></i>
         <div class="tree-label " ng-class="selectedClass()" ng-click="selectNodeLabel(node)" tree-transclude="">
            <table class="ng-scope">
               <tbody>
                  <tr>
                     <td class="tree-label-icon"><img bf-image-path="team" class="tree-icon" src="/Assets/img/icons/team.png"></td>
                     <td class="tree-label-name ng-binding">
                        Approver<br>
                        <progress-bar ng-if="::!node.isFolder" value="1" max-value="230" class="ng-scope">
                           <div class="progress-bar" ng-style="barStyles">
                              <div class="progress-bar-value" ng-style="valueStyles" style="width: 0.434783%;"></div>
                           </div>
                        </progress-bar>
                     </td>
                     <td width="30" class="text-right">
                     <strong class="process-bar-total ng-binding ng-scope" ng-if="::!node.isFolder">1</strong><!-- end ngIf: ::!node.isFolder -->
                     </td>
                  </tr>
               </tbody>
            </table>
         </div>
      </li>
      <li ng-repeat="node in node.children | filter:filterExpression:filterComparator" ng-class="headClass(node)" class="ng-scope tree-collapsed">
         <i class="tree-branch-head" ng-class="iBranchClass()" ng-click="selectNodeHead(node)"></i><i class="tree-leaf-head "></i>
         <div class="tree-label " ng-class="selectedClass()" ng-click="selectNodeLabel(node)" tree-transclude="">
            <table class="ng-scope">
               <tbody>
                  <tr>
                     <td class="tree-label-icon"><img bf-image-path="team" class="tree-icon" src="/Assets/img/icons/team.png"></td>
                     <td class="tree-label-name ng-binding">
                        Assigner<br>
                        <progress-bar ng-if="::!node.isFolder" value="230" max-value="230" class="ng-scope">
                           <div class="progress-bar" ng-style="barStyles">
                              <div class="progress-bar-value" ng-style="valueStyles" style="width: 100%;"></div>
                           </div>
                        </progress-bar>
                     </td>
                     <td width="30" class="text-right">
                      <strong class="process-bar-total ng-binding ng-scope" ng-if="::!node.isFolder">230</strong><!-- end ngIf: ::!node.isFolder -->
                     </td>
                  </tr>
               </tbody>
            </table>
         </div>
      </li>
   </ul>
</treecontrol>
```

This is my code which does not seem to perform he click action.

```
WebElement inboxTypeToSelect =  webdriver.findElement(By.xpath("//treecontrol[@class='ng-isolate-scope']/ul/li/div/table/tbody/tr/td[@class='tree-label-name ng-binding' and normalize-space(text() = '" +  inboxType + "')]"));
Actions action = new Actions(webdriver);
action.click(inboxTypeToSelect);
action.perform();
```

The value passed to `inboxType` is `Approver` so the xpath is:

```
//treecontrol[@class='ng-isolate-scope']/ul/li/div/table/tbody/tr/td[@class='tree-label-name ng-binding' and normalize-space(text() = 'Approver')]
```

Any idea why the action is not performed?

Comment: Did it throw any exception Or is it just element is not clicked?

Comment: No exceptions thrown. Seems as if the first option is selected.

Comment: I have an idea that I need to look for the `li` that contains the `td` with the `class` and `text` mentioned but I am not sure how to do that.

Comment: try with updated XPATH in my answer. checked it is matching only one element which you required.

Answer (score 1):

try the following xpath:

```
//tr/td[contains(text(),"Approver")]
```

try as follows:

```
 WebElement inboxTypeToSelect =  webdriver.findElement(By.xpath("//tr/td[contains(text(),"Approver")]"));
    Actions action = new Actions(webdriver);
    action.click(inboxTypeToSelect).perform();
```

call perform() after the click method.

instead of action chains use click on WebElement itself.

```
WebElement inboxTypeToSelect =  webdriver.findElement(By.xpath("//tr/td[contains(text(),"Approver")]"));
inboxTypeToSelect.click();
```

Comment: not working? not able to find the element? unique element is found but not able to click on it? please elaborate your scenario. the XPTATH you tried matching with 3 elements. Is it the issue?

Comment: Will this not look for everything that will have text Approver? If so then it is not the most elegant approach as I might have other elements on my page which also contains this text.

Comment: added uniqueness -;. please try now. and you can further improve uniqueness by adding more parent element in the beginning.

Comment: I found the problem. The brackets at the normalize-space was not correct. Should be `normalize-space(text()) = '" +  inboxType + "'` instead of `normalize-space(text() = '" +  inboxType + ")'`

Comment: Naveen, I didn't check.

Answer (score 0):

you can find the right td of Approver by xpath:

> html/body/treecontrol/ul/li[2]/div/table/tbody/tr/td[2]

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/treecontrol/ul/li[2]/div/table/tbody/tr/td[2]")).click();
```

Comment: It's not the best idea to use absolute `XPath`

Comment: I don't want to hardcode the `li[2]` because eventually I want the input value to be data driven.